# Generate serial values based on change in composite key value changes

Tags: postgresql

I am creating the table

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.TEST_SERIAL(
    SEQ BIGSERIAL,
    KEY1 VARCHAR(20),
    KEY2 VARCHAR(20),
    SOMEVALUE VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(SEQ,KEY1,KEY2)
);
```

I want to generate SEQ start again from 1 based on the KEY1 value changes

```
INSERT INTO TEST.TEST_SERIAL(KEY1,KEY2,SOMEVALUE) VALUES ('ABC','123456','Test1');
INSERT INTO TEST.TEST_SERIAL(KEY1,KEY2,SOMEVALUE) VALUES ('ABC','193456','Test1');
INSERT INTO TEST.TEST_SERIAL(KEY1,KEY2,SOMEVALUE) VALUES ('ABC','783456','Test1');
INSERT INTO TEST.TEST_SERIAL(KEY1,KEY2,SOMEVALUE) VALUES ('BCD','123456','Test1');
INSERT INTO TEST.TEST_SERIAL(KEY1,KEY2,SOMEVALUE) VALUES ('BCD','453456','Test1');
INSERT INTO TEST.TEST_SERIAL(KEY1,KEY2,SOMEVALUE) VALUES ('EFG','123456','Test1');
```

tried below function and trigger getting error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION gen_seq() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
begin
  NEW.seq := nextval('gen_seq_' || NEW.key1);
  RETURN NEW;
end
$$;
CREATE TRIGGER gen_seq BEFORE INSERT ON TEST.TEST_SERIAL FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE gen_seq();
```

> ERROR:  relation "gen_seq_abc" does not existCONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function gen_seq() line 3 at assignment

Please help me if there is any alternative.

Comment: Why define the column `seq` as `bigserial` if you want to use a completely different sequence to populate it? You also never created the sequences `gen_seq_abc`, `gen_seq_bcd` and `gen_seq_efg`, so why do you expect the `nextval()` to work in your trigger function?

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name thank you so much for your response. 

Frankly i am noob, with the databases. "gen_seq_abc" basically i suppose to use the column_id here in trigger to get the nextval()?

Comment: tried changing it to integer, still getting same error in the function

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the sequences before you can use them in the trigger:

```
create sequence gen_seq_abc;
create sequence gen_seq_bcd;
create sequence gen_seq_efg;
```

Then the INSERTs will work.

However you will need to know the possible values for `key1` in advance. Otherwise an INSERT with an "unknown" key1 will fail again.

Comment: Hi, I will end up creating n+ sequences in this case.. is there any way to invoke the column value from key1 and then use it to restart the sequence from 1 when key1!=key1

Comment: @gokul: What do you mean by "when key1!=key1"? When is that?